# Figure of merit for multiple simulations of point patterns

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, cumulative-distribution-function

I am having problems understanding how I can evaluate a set of (Monte Carlo) simulations based on randomly distributed points.

Assume you simulate a random point pattern in a square and you plot the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the nearest neighbor distances. Repeat the simulation, let's say 10 times, and evaluate the corresponding 10 CDFs. The mean value of those 10 CDFs shall be my "expected distribution".

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, 
squareform


font_size = 20
line_width = 2

number_of_points = 50
density = 100
x_min = 0
x_max = np.sqrt(number_of_points/ density)
y_min = 0
y_max = np.sqrt(number_of_points/ density)

simulations = 10
```

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
realizations = 0
arr_list = []
dots_sim = []
matrix = []
coordinates = []
distances = []

while realizations < simulations:
    dots_sim = []
    new_dot = True
    dots_sim.append((np.random.uniform(x_min, x_max), np.random.uniform(y_min, y_max)))
    while new_dot:
        x = np.random.uniform(x_min, x_max)
        y = np.random.uniform(y_min, y_max)
        dots_sim.append((x, y))
        if len(dots_sim) == number_of_points:
            new_dot = False
        
    dots_sim = np.array(dots_sim)
    coordinates.append(dots_sim)
    distances_sim = pdist(dots_sim, 'euclidean')
    cd_matrix = squareform(distances_sim)

    m = cd_matrix.shape[0]
    strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    s0, s1 = cd_matrix.strides
    out = strided(cd_matrix.ravel()[1:], shape=(m - 1, m), strides=(s0 + s1, s1)).reshape(m, -1)

    nnd_sim = []

    for i in range(len(out)):
        nnd_sim.append(np.min(out[i]))

    nnd_sim = np.sort(nnd_sim)
    distances.append(nnd_sim)

    arr_list.append(nnd_sim)
    realizations += 1
    print('simulated patterns:', realizations)

matrix = np.column_stack(arr_list)

mean_simulation = []
for i in range(number_of_points):
    mean_simulation.append(np.mean(matrix[i]))

y_cdf = np.array(range(number_of_points)) / float(number_of_points)

# CDF
for i in range(simulations):
    plt.plot(distances[i], y_cdf, '--', alpha=0.3, linewidth=line_width)
plt.plot(mean_simulation, y_cdf, '-', label='Avg. Simulation Value', linewidth=line_width)
plt.xlabel('Nearest Neighbor Distance [$\mathrm{\mu}$m]', fontsize=font_size)
plt.ylabel('Cumulative Probability', fontsize=font_size)
plt.xticks(fontsize=font_size)
plt.yticks(fontsize=font_size)
plt.legend(fontsize=font_size)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I statistically determine correctly how good those 10 simulations are?

More precisely:
Is there a "global value" that I can calculate and compare for different numbers of distributed points, depending on the number of the simulations? My general assumptions are:

1. More points OR more simulations result in better statistics.
2. Simulating 10 points 10x is statistically equal to 5x 20 points.

**What I tried so far:**
Taking the cross-section at y_cdf[i] and evaluating SciPy's norm.fit. The standard deviation shows me, that the number of simulations is normally distributed around the mean value. Then I tried to sum up the standard deviation for each y_cdf value and divided it by the square root of the number of simulated points, but that looked strange.

[image]

I do not even know if this actually IS the standard error of the mean value. I think it is definitely not correct because it should be below 5%, because of the fact that according to the norm.fit most simulations are in the 95% confidence interval...In another try, I treated each point of every simulation as an independent value and summed up each quadratic deviation from a point to the simulation mean value (n points x k simulations) and divided this by n(n-1), then taking the squareroot (corrected sample standard deviation?).

[image]

mhhh....I also thought of determining the RSS for ONE simulation and then summing up for all simulations and dividing it by the number of simulations. To be honest: It starts to be more of a guessing game because I do not know how to deal with it.

I appreciate your help!